# Implementing Bootstrap BlueImp Gallery in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement the Bootstrap BlueImp Gallery plugin with my Rails application.

So far my code looks as follows:

```
<div id="links">


<%= link_to image_tag('image-thumb.jpg'), 'image.jpg', data: {gallery: ''} %>

</div>
```

The thumbnail of the image loads correctly and when clicked the screen darkens however nothing appears in the darkened screen. I suspect the error lies within the

```
data: {gallery: ''}
```

snippet but am unsure why or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <%= link_to image_tag("#{image.gsub("app/assets/images/", "")}", height: '110', width: '110'), ("assets/" + "#{image.gsub("app/assets/images/", "")}"), :data => {:gallery => 'gallery'}, :title => 'Aloha' %>
```

Path to full size image was not correct and had to be amended to include 'assets/'